# EF Core OnDelete restrict adds additional column

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have models in a many-to-many relationship:

User

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Role

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RolePrivilege> RolePrivileges { get; set; }
}
```

UserRole

```
public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

When I created migrations and then tried update-database, it threw an error of multiple cascade paths. The solution to this was to make On Delete, No Action so I added this in OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasIndex(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId })
            .IsUnique();

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasOne(e => e.User)
        .WithMany()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
}
```

Now the tables are created but one thing that I wasn't expecting is its making an extra column. The migration code looks like this after generating:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                UserId1 = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserRoles", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserRoles_Roles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "Roles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserRoles_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserRoles_Users_UserId1",
                    column: x => x.UserId1,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

As you can see, it added an extra column, UserId1.

What am I doing wrong or how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a result of a typical relationship fluent configuration mistake - using a parameterless overload of `Has` / `With` (effectively telling EF that there is no corresponding navigation property) while actually a navigation property exists. In that case EF will map the missing navigation property to **another** relationship with no navigation property at the other end and default by convention FK property/column name.

To fix the issue, make sure to use the correct overloads which represent the presence/absence of a navigation property (and update them according in case you add/remove navigation property). In your case, replace

```
.WithMany()
```

with

```
.WithMany(e => e.UserRoles)
```